# How to pass string in html into txt document at specified path?

Tags: html, asp.net

I am trying out ASP.NET right now and do not understand how to pass a stored information in a string into a textfile. How do I do it?

Comment: Post some of the code you already have.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string myString = "Sample String Text";
//The @ character defines a verbatim string literal.
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\text.txt"))
   {
     sw.WriteLine(myString);
   }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

With the download feature of js.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).